# iOS 7 Phone app interface doesn't show "Decline" button when it's asleep

Tags: iphone, ios

In iOS 7, when the phone is in Sleep mode and I receive a call, I don't see the "Decline" button. All I see is a green "Answer..." button that requires me to slide to the right to answer the call. Is there anyway we can change that? I know that there are buttons for "Remind Me Later, etc" but I want the "Decline" button.

It works fine when the phone is not in Sleep mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple press the power button once to decline the call. Notification center will keep a reminder for you about the missed call.

EDIT: Pressing the power button once registers as an ignore. Pressing it twice will drop the call to voicemail.

Comment: I don't want any notifications to be added to my notification center. I receive many calls and most of the time I simply want to decline them.

Comment: If you press the power button once it ignores the call, if you press it twice it rejects the call and sends them directly to voicemail. Not sure if that leaves a notification or not.

Comment: Works. But do you know how to configure my Voice Mail? I don't see anything in there.

Comment: I think if you go into the phone app then to the Voicemail section on the bottom there is a "greeting" at the top left. If you select it you can choose your greeting. If you are needing to set up voice mail I think you can find the settings for that in the Phone section of the Settings app.